# Insert record if all values do not exist in a row

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have three columns: a, b, c.

I want to INSERT a new row if a, b, c do not already exist into a row.

Using Python to do this.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(column_a, column_b, column_c) 
VALUES(value_a, value_b, value_c) 
WHERE value_a, value_b, value_c are all unique in existing rows.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine with implementing a general mechanism to avoid duplicates on columns column_a/b/c, you can simply add a composite unique constraint on both columns, like

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD CONSTRAINT constr_ID UNIQUE (column_a, column_b, column_c);
```

If anything operation happens on the table that would generate duplicates, MySQL will raise a constraint violation error. You can ignore the error with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option :

```
INSERT INTO mytable(column_a, column_b, column_c)
VALUES(value_a, value_b, value_c)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_a = column_a;
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cYesbAB9ntKoY6CLXJ1oQK/1)**, we are inserting 3 records with 2 duplicates, and we end up with 2 records in the table, as expected.

---

On the other hand, if you want to restrict the check on duplicate to just one query, and/or if you want to avoid wasting autoincrement sequences on duplicate keys, then you can turn to an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` condition that does the duplicate check :

```
INSERT INTO mytable(column_a, column_b, column_c)
SELECT src.*
FROM (SELECT value_a column_a, value_b column_b, value_c column_c) src
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        column_a = src.column_a 
        AND column_b = src.column_b 
        AND column_c = src.column_c
);
```

If you attempt to insert a duplicate, the query will do nothing (and will not generate an error or warning).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cYesbAB9ntKoY6CLXJ1oQK/0)**.

Comment: I tried out the first implementation, but nothing is getting inserted into my table.

Comment: @brainygrunt : if you try to insert duplicates, then nothing gets inserted. Else, the record gets inserted.

Comment: Agreed. But nothing at all gets inserted. Since the table is currently empty, there should at least be one row inserted.

Comment: @brainygrunt : see [this DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cYesbAB9ntKoY6CLXJ1oQK/1) that demonstrates how the functionality works.

Comment: thanks! this works. however, my id autoincrement is skipping numbers like 1, 2, 6, 40, 121 etc.

Comment: Welcome @brainygrunt. Yes `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` does waste autoincrement values. If that's a problem for you then you can consider switching to the second solution I provided...

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is to create a unique index on the three columns. The database will reject the insert if you attempt to insert a duplicate row. No special query is required. This should work on any relational database, not just MySQL.

Create the unique index with this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_b_c ON mytable (column_a, column_b, column_c)
```

Insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(column_a, column_b, column_c) VALUES (value_a, value_b, value_c)
```

If there already exists a row with the same values for columns `column_a`, `column_b`, and `column_c` the database will reject the insert and you will see an exception in Python.

Comment: `insert IGNONE` may be usable here (if one do not need to report it back to user)

Comment: @fifonik: sure, if that is acceptable, but OP didn't indicate that.

Comment: keep in mind `INSERT IGONE` on the innoDB table engine will "waste" auto_increment values when the insert failed @fifonik

Comment: Also `INSERT IGNORE` turns **all** errors into warnings, not just duplicate keys errors. This can be tricky. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is the way to go.